# Install GCC on a linux machine where there is no internet connection

Tags: linux, gcc

Is there any way to install GCC on a redhat machine which has no internet connection.

Can i download the package from somewhere and install?

Comment: Either get the packages from *Redhat*, or use the Redhat CentOS packages http://mirror.centos.org/centos/ . Requirements: glibc-devel, glibc-headers, kernel-headers, gcc, (gcc-c++,  libstdc++-devel) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could just download the Tarball at on of the mirror sites https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html put it on i.e. an usb-Stick
and extract it on your computer with `tar -zxf {path to the tar.gz file.}`
and run the gcc file in the extracted folder.

Comment: Could you elaborate on running gcc file ?

Comment: What do you mean with "run the gcc file in the extracted folder"? pleace elaborate